# Add window.location to body class

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, window.location

I am trying to put together a smooth scrolling nav that as you are scrolling the entire header encompassing the menu changes background colors to match the defined color of that section. I am using Foundation 6 with the magellan feature for my nav.

I am trying to get my JS to get the current URL and add a class to the body that is the current URL.

```
var current_location = window.location.href.split('/');
var page = current_location[current_location.length - 1];
```

This gets me my URL hash (i.e.: #section2, #section3). I need to watch that as it changes on scroll of the page and add those to the body class while removing the previous one after you leave that section.

Comment: You can use `window.location.hash` to get the URL hash. But why is the hash changing when you scroll, is there something doing that? Then you can add a listener for the `hashchange` event.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went about it a different method, wanted to post it here for reference:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    var headerHeight = $('#header').height() + $('.bottom-header').height() - 4;

    var x = $(this).scrollTop(),
        section1 = $('#section1'),
        section2 = $('#section2'),
        section3 = $('#section3'),
        section4 = $('#section4');
        section5 = $('#section51-a');


    if (x >= section1.offset().top && x < (section1.offset().top + section1.height())) {
        $('.top-header').css("background-color", "#cc00cc");
    }


    if (x >= (section2.offset().top - headerHeight) && x < (section2.offset().top + section2.height())) {
        $('.top-header').css("background-color", "#009999");
    }
    if (x >= (section3.offset().top - headerHeight) && x < (section3.offset().top + section3.height())) {

        $('.top-header').css("background-color", "#ea148c");
    }
    if (x >= (section4.offset().top - headerHeight) && x < (section4.offset().top + section4.height())) {
        $('.top-header').css("background-color", "#999900");
    }
    if (x >= (section5.offset().top - headerHeight) && x < (section5.offset().top + section5.height())) {
        $('.top-header').css("background-color", "#0066cc");
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some mechanism/widget which changes the `hash` whenever you scroll your page And as suggested by @Barmar you can try following code:

```
var oldHashValue = ""; //defining the global variable to store old hash value class

$(function() {
  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
  // hash and adds it as a class to <body> tag.

  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = location.hash;

    //remove the previously added class from <body> only if its not a blank string
    if($.trim(oldHashValue).length > 0)
    {
        $("body").removeClass(oldHashValue);
    }

    oldHashValue = hash.replace( /^#/, "" ); //set the variable value
    if($.trim(oldHashValue).length > 0)
    {
        //add the class to body element
        $("body").addClass(oldHashValue);
    }
  });
  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).trigger("hashchange");
});
```

Comment: so when I add this I get in my console "$(...).hashchange is not a function".... I have this wrapped my document.ready();

Comment: oh..I missed that one. could you please check now with updated code?

Comment: Seems to be error'ing on this line:  $( window ).hashchange(); "$(...).hashchange is not a function" ... thank you for your help, really appreciate it

Comment: @Danny - could you please replace that line with `$(window).on('hashchange', function() {`

Comment: or better way; replace your code with updated code which i modified just now.

Comment: Ok stopped generating an error, but nothing is being added to the body. http://pastie.org/10964075 | using this btw: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html